# set values as a variable of select tag in php

Tags: php, html

I want to set both values as variable. Means if I want to use sales or training as a variable and if I want to use its value anywhere then I can use it.

```
<form action="code.php" method="post">
    <select name="department">  
        <option>Please Choose Department</option>
        <option value="sales">Sales</option>
        <option value="training">Training</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I am trying by below code but I can't.

**code1.php**

```
<?php
    $stud = explode("_", $_POST['department']);
    $sales = $stud[0];
    $training = $stud[1];
    echo "$sales";
    echo "$training";
?>
```

`$sales` and `$training` are not working as variable.

Please help.

Comment: Did u mean that u want to select both the values in the select box ?? If so, use `multiple` attribute of the select box to select multiple options `<select name='department' multiple>`

Comment: Does the $stud array take the data correctly? try print_r to view what it contains may help in your referencing

Comment: I have updated question, please check. Thank you

Comment: based on the data you have in your question, you have nothing with a `_` in it, therefore you *should* get an 'undefined offset: 1' error on the `$training = ..` line.

Comment: Is any other way to find my answer? Please help.

Comment: Yes,I have find      'undefined offset: 1' error.  How can I get true value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are looking for this:

```
<form action="code.php" method="post">
    <select name="department[]" multiple>  
        <option>Please Choose Department</option>
        <option value="sales">Sales</option>
        <option value="training">Training</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<?php
    $sales = $_POST['department'][0];
    $training = $_POST['department'][1];
    echo $sales;
    echo $training;
?>
```

`select` must be defined as multiple select and as array in name.

Comment: Great! Pick up and check any answer in order to close the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Update

```
<select name="department">
```

With

```
<select name="department[]" multiple>
```

PHP Part

```
<?php
$stud = $_POST['department'];
extract($stud);
echo $sales;
echo $training;
?>
```

Explanation:

We have used `multiple` attribute of `<select>` so that multiple options can be selected.

If we use multiple as select, the value getting posted as array. So, no need to explode it.

Then we [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) ed the posted array to get two desired elements.

Comment: `name="department[]"` will be better :)